# WPF INotifyPropertyChanged not work from call another class

Tags: c#, wpf, inotifypropertychanged

I have MainModel:

```
public class MainModel: INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public MainModel {
        AllList = new ObservableCollection<MyClassType>();
        GetList();
    }

    private ObservableCollection<MyClassType> _allList;
    public ObservableCollection<MyClassType> AllList 
    {
        get
        {
            return _allList;
        }
        set
        {
            if (value == _allList) return;
            _allList= value;
            OnPropertyChanged("AllList");
        }

    }
     public void GetList()
     {
      AllList = (..get from DataBase)
      }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        var handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null) 
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

On MainProgram in cs:

```
public static MainModel MainModel;    
public MainProgram()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        MainModel = new MainModel();
        DataContext = MainModel;           
    }
```

On MainProgram in xaml:

```
 <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=AllList}"/>
```

It's work on run application, listbox view ListBox Items!
Ok, good. Project have AnotherModel:

```
class AnotherModel :INotifyPropertyChanged {
...
public void AddNewItem(MyPropertiers properties)
...
}
public Save(){
var prop = new MyPropertiers {name = NameProperty, Size = SizeProperty
AddNewItem(prop);
//!!! 
}
}
```

Where !!! - New item added in DataBase Table, and i want to reload ListBoxItems, i called MainModel.GetList, but this GetList is not static, and if i call "new MainModel().GetList();" - ListBox not reloaded, why? may be not call NEW MainModel

Comment: Have you tried breaking in the method used to refresh the listbox and see if the data is updated or not? It may just not be getting raised to the UI.

Comment: If you "new" then that will be a new one.  Why not just add Prop to AllList?

Comment: Also it looks like your updating the list but raising the property changed event on MainModel and not on your views. Calling your OnPropertyChanged("name") method is the same as this.OnPropertyChanged(...) to notify the other window you would need raise the PropertyChanged event on that window to update the property there: MyView.OnPropertyChanged(...).

Comment: yes, new MainModel().GetList() worked, and AllList get all records from DB, but Listbox not shown new data. ListBox have old data. May be because it is caused by a new instance MainModel?

Comment: If you call your static `MainModel.GetList()`, does the check in the setter return true for `if (value == _allList) return;`? And yes, your ListBox is bound to the static `MainModel.AllList`, so creating a new `MainModel` will of course create a different version of the `AllList` property, which is not bound to the ListBox

Comment: Rachel, yes, how to resolve?

Comment: First you need to create a link between two model. May be you can create an event and raise the event when new items added to the database. Once the event is raised you can again GetList from the DB.